# how to set value from barcode in core data swift

Tags: swift, core-data, barcode

I have a code was read by barcode after reading it I want to put the value of the core data

this output barcode code

```
func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputMetadataObjects metadataObjects: [AnyObject]!, fromConnection connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {

        // Check if the metadataObjects array is not nil and it contains at least one object.
        if metadataObjects == nil || metadataObjects.count == 0 {
            qrCodeFrameView?.frame = CGRectZero

            return
        }

        // Get the metadata object.
        let metadataObj = metadataObjects[0] as! AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject

        // Here we use filter method to check if the type of metadataObj is supported
        // Instead of hardcoding the AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode, we check if the type
        // can be found in the array of supported bar codes.
        if supportedBarCodes.filter({ $0 == metadataObj.type }).count > 0 {
            // If the found metadata is equal to the QR code metadata then update the status label's text and set the bounds
            let barCodeObject = videoPreviewLayer?.transformedMetadataObjectForMetadataObject(metadataObj as AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject) as! AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject
            qrCodeFrameView?.frame = barCodeObject.bounds

            println(metadataObj.stringValue)

        }

    }
```

this core data code

```
let newItem = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Codes", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext!) as! Codes

            newItem.code = metadataObj.stringValue
```

Comment: You did not provide any details of your core data setup.

Comment: What you get after scanning a bar code is just a string. So you just want to save a string to core data. As long as you get a scanned string, your issue has nothing to do with bar code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save your changes to Core Data, for example:

```
context.save(nil)
```

where context is your NSManagetObjectContext.

You should check your local SQL lite database - a common sqlite Viewer is very helpful to check CoreData changes.

Answer (score 0):

assign a variable name to metadataObj.stringValue like var a = metadataObj.stringValue, then save it in a persistence context